# Any integer can be written as $x^2+4y^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

*If $n$ is a positive integer with $(n,8)=1$ and $-4$ is square $mod$ $n$ then $n$ can be written in this form:
$n=x^2+4y^2$.*

I was using that there are x, y integers satisfying $x^2+4y^2=kn$ where $0<k<4$, let's consider $k=1,2,3$

1. If $k=1$ the result is completed.
2. If $k=2$,  $x^2+4y^2=2n$, then $x^2=2n$ $mod$ $n$
   as $(n,8)=1$ $n$ is odd, so $n=2t+1$
   thus, $x^2=2n=4t+2$ $mod$ $n$, this is $x^2=2$ $mod$ $n$, but it cannot be true because an square is always $0$ or $1$ $mod$ $4$.
3. Now when $k=3$, I haven't found anything.
   Anybody can help me!
   Every idea is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does $(n,8)=1$ mean $\gcd(n,8)=1$?? If so that's a strange way to say that $n$ is odd. [or an odd way to say it. ;)]

Comment: Yes, $mcd(n,8)=1$. I think I maybe will need this for the proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the most elementary way is to use the fact that if all prime divisors of $n$ are of the form $4k+1$ then one can represent $n=a^2+b^2,$ which is a direct consequence of Fermat's theorem on two squares. Since $n$ is odd, one has that either $a$ or $b$ is even. Hence, $n=a^2+4b_1^2.$
So we are left to show that all prime divisors of $n$ are of the form $4k+1.$
Indeed, since there is such $x,$ that $x^2=-4(\mod p)$ we can raise both sides to the power $(p-1)/2$ and apply Fermat's Little  theorem to get $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}=1(\mod p).$ Thus, $(p-1)/2$ has to be even and the result follows.

Comment: thanks! It was very useful!